# Rendimiento de UPDATE con Oracle y Delphi XE7

Tags: delphi, sql-server-2014, oracle-12c

Me encuentro realizando pruebas de rendimiento de ArrayDML de FireDAC de Delphi XE7, con conexión a SQL Server 14 y Oracle 12cR2, estoy realizando un UPDATE masivo de 20,000 filas, pero encuentro una gran diferencia entre SQL Server (el cual termina en 28sg) y Oracle (que termina en 3min 17sg), los datos son exactamente los mismos, se trata de una tabla que actualiza todos sus campos (238 campos) en una valor distinto por cada fila y en el WHERE se filtra por la PK, que consta de 14 columnas, el update es muy simple:

```
UPDATE COSAS SET CAMPO1=:P1, CAMPO2=:P2, ......(238 CAMPOS)
WHERE (CAMPO1=:P1 AND CAMPO2=:P2 ......(14 CAMPOS));
```

¿Sabrán a que se debe la gran diferencia de rendimiento que obtengo en Oracle?

Comment: FireDAC implementa el ArrayDML en ambas bases de datos de manera nativa, sin emulación, por lo que sospecho que el problema podría estar en la base de datos, pero no mencionas qué comprobaciones has hecho para determinar que el problema está en FireDac y no en la base de datos subyacente, que puede ser más lenta una que otra por temas de diseño, triggers, etc. 
Por otro lado, si no mencionas si has visto el monitor SQL de FireDAC para tu aplicación y qué es lo que este arroja.

Comment: No creo que el problema se encuentre en FireDAC, como bien mencionas es más un problema de la BD, mi pregunta va encaminada hacia si sabes de algún cambio que se pueda realizar en Oracle para que no sea tanto el tiempo de ejecución o a que se debe que sea tan lento si son UPDATE's simples

Comment: He estado investigando y he visto el uso de FORALL pero no es algo que yo requiera debido a que su uso es con PL/SQL y en este caso simplemente es la sentencia SQL o BULK COLLECT

Comment: Por otro lado, no sé como ver el monitor SQL de FireDAC que mencionas:( revise las trazas en cada gestor y en SQL Server vi los 20mil updates, en Oracle solo me aparece 1 y lo que se va modificando son los valores, el diseño de las bases de datos es el mismo, de hecho la BD fue migrada de SQL Server a Oracle

Comment: El tema de optimizar bases de datos es bastante profundo. Sospecho que puedes tener problemas de desempeño en general. Quizás el servidor de base de datos esté configurado de una forma sub-óptima, en comparación con SQL Server, quizás el hardware sea inferior, o quizás el camino de _migración_ de la estructura no tuvo en cuenta las particularidades de Oracle. Es algo difícil de decir con la información disponible.

Comment: Sobre el [monitor SQL](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Tracing_and_Monitoring_(FireDAC)), ya que has visto lo que pasa a bajo nivel en cada uno de los motores, ya no es necesario, pero te dejo la referencia porque es el tipo de cosas que ayudan a _observar_ lo que ocurre tras bambalinas cuando se trabaja con bases de datos utilizando FireDAC.

Comment: Las pruebas fueron realizadas en el mismo equipo, tenía habilitada la traza para la instancia de Oracle, la deshabilite y el tiempo bajo, ¿sabrás de alguna otra configuración que pueda ayudarme con este tema de optimización?

Comment: En un insert/update lo qué más puede hacer la diferencia: Triggers, índices, I/O, Logs. Entre SQLServer y Oracle puede haber diferencias sensibles en todos, y Oracle tiene una maquinaria más potente para poder diagnosticar esto, sin embargo el tema es muy amplio. Te recomiendo comprar algunos libros o conseguir ayuda profesional para evaluar el tema.